# Read 1st column, 2nd column, and nth column to last column of panda dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df`.

There are 27 columns in `df`.

I want to read the 1st, 2nd and 10th to the last columns of `df`. I can do this `df.iloc[0,1,9,10,11,.....,26]` but this is too tedious to type if the dataframe has many columns. What is a more elegant way to read the columns?

I am using python v3.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like to select columns by their numerical index, `iloc` is the right thing to use. You can use `np.arange` add a range of columns (such as between the 10th to the last one).

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np

cols = [0, 1]
cols.extend(np.arange(10, df.shape[1]))
df.iloc[:,cols]
```

Alternatively, you can use numpy's `r_` slicing trick:

```
df.iloc[:,np.r_[0:2, 10:df.shape[1]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "list" and "range":

```
df.iloc[:,[0,1]+list(range(9,27))]
```

Or numpy way:

```
df.iloc[:,np.append([0,1],np.arange(9,27))]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the column names, you can try :

```
df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'coln']]
```

If you don't know the exact column names, you can try this :

```
list_of_columns_index = [1,2,3, n]
df = df[[df.columns[i] for i in list_of_columns_index]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you know the name of the starting column or name of column 10th in your context. Assume name is `starting_column_name`.

Using name of column will make the code more readable and you save the trouble of counting columns to get to the right one.

```
num_columns = df.shape[1]  # number of columns in dataframe
starting_column = df.columns.get_loc(starting_column_name)
features = df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:2, starting_column:num_columns]]
```